# How can I add points to a LineString in shapely?

Tags: python, shapely

I have two `Polygons` which intersect along one edge as shown below.

[image]

I need to add the red vertices at each end of the intersection to the blue polygon. I thought I could do this with by calling `union` on the `Polygon` and the `LineString` produced by `intersection` of the two polygons but it appears not.

Is there a way of doing what I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the properties of `union` (and `unary_union`) witch split all the lines at intersections ([Planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph))

[image]

```
# LinearRing of the polygons
ringgreen = LineString(list(polygreen.exterior.coords))
ringblue  = LineString(list(polyblue.exterior.coords))
# Union of the rings
union = ringgreen.union(ringblue)
# now polygonize the result
from shapely.ops import polygonize
result = [geom for geom in polygonize(union]
```

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: That's actually just a less-roundabout way of doing what I was already doing. Thanks to your post confirming what is supposed to happen, I've found that I was getting tripped up by the fact I was translating my polygons first, then trying to do the `union` step. That was then failing because of floating point errors.