# Rounding all coordinates in shapely?

Tags: python, shapely, floating-point

Following on from [How can I add points to a LineString in shapely?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188594), I'm hitting a problem where floating point representations mean objects aren't precisely where I expect them be after they are moved using `affinity.translate`.

This would be fixed if there was a way of rounding all the coordinates to the nearest cm (or other insignificantly-small value).

Does this exist?

---

For what it's worth, I'm doing all my intersection and union operations first before the translation and that seems to be working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Shapely and GEOS cannot reduce precision (floating-point precision problem) but you can use other functions as `numpy.round()` or `round()`,with the GeoJSON format.

For polygons

```
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping
import numpy as np
# one polygon
print poly.wkt
POLYGON ((101.2200527190607 -114.6493019170767, 146.6225142079163 -114.4488495484725, 185.0301801801801 -114.2792792792793, 184.6581081081081 -217.7153153153153, 14.99324324324321 -218.4594594594595, 16.4815315315315 -115.0234234234234, 101.2200527190607 -114.6493019170767))
# convert to GeoJSON format
geojson = mapping(poly)
print geojson
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((101.2200527190607, -114.6493019170767), (146.6225142079163, -114.4488495484725), (185.0301801801801, -114.2792792792793), (184.6581081081081, -217.7153153153153), (14.99324324324321, -218.4594594594595), (16.4815315315315, -115.0234234234234), (101.2200527190607, -114.6493019170767)),)}
 geojson['coordinates'] = np.round(np.array(geojson['coordinates']),2)
 print geojson
 {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': array([[[ 101.22, -114.65],
    [ 146.62, -114.45],
    [ 185.03, -114.28],
    [ 184.66, -217.72],
    [  14.99, -218.46],
    [  16.48, -115.02],
    [ 101.22, -114.65]]])}
 print shape(geojson)
 POLYGON ((101.22 -114.65, 146.62 -114.45, 185.03 -114.28, 184.66 -217.72, 14.99 -218.46, 16.48 -115.02, 101.22 -114.65))
```

If you don't want to use Numpy, you can adapt the function `def _set_precision(coords, precision)` of the [geojson-precision](https://github.com/perrygeo/geojson-precision) module

```
 def set_precision(coords, precision):
    result = []
    try:
        return round(coords, int(precision))
    except TypeError:
        for coord in coords:
            result.append(set_precision(coord, precision))
    return result
 geojson = mapping(poly)
 geojson['coordinates']= set_precision(geojson['coordinates'], 2)
 print geojson
 {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[101.22, -114.65], [146.62, -114.45], [185.03, -114.28], [184.66, -217.72], [14.99, -218.46], [16.48, -115.02], [101.22, -114.65]]]}
 print shape(geojson)
 POLYGON ((101.22 -114.65, 146.62 -114.45, 185.03 -114.28, 184.66 -217.72, 14.99 -218.46, 16.48 -115.02, 101.22 -114.65))
```

Comment: isn't there a typo in your alternate code:
result.append(_set_precision(coord, precision)) should be result.append(set_precision(coord, precision)) ???

Comment: Yes, corrected, thanks

Answer (score 16):

There are a few instances where [@gene's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/188739/115) does not work.

For example, the using the overprecise value `-73.92391000000001`

```
geojson = {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-73.92391, 41.31064], [-73.92391, 41.31069], [-73.92388, 41.31069], [-73.92388, 41.31064], [-73.92391, 41.31064]]]}
print(str(shape(geojson)))
POLYGON ((-73.92391000000001 41.31064, -73.92391000000001 41.31069, -73.92388 41.31069, -73.92388 41.31064, -73.92391000000001 41.31064))
```

**EDIT (MAY 2019)**: I recommend a roundtrip using `shapely.wkt.dumps` method instead, where `rounding_precision=n` is the n'th decimal point to which you want the coordinates rounded:

```
shapely.wkt.loads(shapely.wkt.dumps(geom, rounding_precision=n))
```

Comment: And to remove sequential duplicates created by rounding: `shapely.wkt.loads(...).simplify(0)`.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer. However what about performances ?

Answer (score 2):

while there isn't a built in method or function in shapely you can use `shapely.ops.transform` to write a utility function to round coordinates for any geometry, including multipart geometries.

```py
from shapley.ops import transform

def round_coordinates(geom, ndigits=2):
    
   def _round_coords(x, y, z=None):
      x = round(x, ndigits)
      y = round(y, ndigits)

      if z is not None:
          z = round(z, ndigits) # corrected from x to z

      return [c for c in (x, y, z) if c is not None]
   
   return transform(_round_coords, geom)
```

then running it like so

```py
>>> _p = Polygon(((0.01, 1.234), (5.4321, 2.9348343943), (0.00000001, 9.23923), (0.01, 1.234)))
>>> round_coordinates(_p, 2).wkt
'POLYGON ((0.01 1.23, 5.43 2.93, 0 9.24, 0.01 1.23))'
```

Comment: imo this is the best answer since it uses the built in shapely transform method instead of converting to some other format. But it throws a weird error for me complaining about a generator. I fixed it by dropping the one line for loop. see here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/445283

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the accepted answer did not work as my geojson was a multi polygon. Doing `np.round(np.array(geosjon['coordinates']),2)` throws a Python exception.

Instead, I wrote a short little recursive function that rounds all floats in a nested list. Meaning, that it also works on a list of list of list of list... for any depth.

```py
def round_nested_list(l, precision):
    def round_element(e):
        if isinstance(e, list):
            return round_nested_list(e, precision)
        else:
            return round(e, precision)
    return [round_element(e) for e in l]

# test
l = [[[1.1123, 1.1123],[[1.1123, 1.1123],[[1.1123, 1.1123],[1.1123, 1.1123]]]], [[1.1123, 1.1123],[[1.1231, 1.1123],[[1.1231, 1.1231],[1.1231, 1.1231]]]]]

round_nested_list(l, 2)

# result is [[[1.11, 1.11], [[1.11, 1.11], [[1.11, 1.11], [1.11, 1.11]]]],
 [[1.11, 1.11], [[1.12, 1.11], [[1.12, 1.12], [1.12, 1.12]]]]]
```

I tried on a multipolygon with 20k+ points, and it took a few seconds. Good for me.

Edit : And if the coordinates are in tuples (at the last level), you can use :

```py
def round_nested_list(l, precision):
    def round_element(e):
        if isinstance(e, list):
            return round_nested_list(e, precision)
        elif isinstance(e, tuple):
            return tuple(round(i, precision) for i in e)
        else:
            return round(e, precision)
    return [round_element(e) for e in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

As of **`shapely 2.0`** (see [release notes](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/release/2.x.html#support-for-fixed-precision-model-for-geometries-and-in-overlay-functions)), a precision model is now available: the [**`set_precision`**](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.set_precision.html#shapely.set_precision) function and the `grid_size` parameter for overlay functions.

However, it's not necessarily behaving as you might expect, see some unexpected results with `contains` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76101394/11222693).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to reduce precision with Shapely even though GEOS, the base geometry engine, has precision reducer classes. You might try ogr2ogr. The geoJson driver has a "Coordinate Precision" option. You can export to geojson then create a shapefile from geojson. Just an idea.