# Float point problems using Shapely using WKT

Tags: python, shapely, floating-point

I am having float point problems using the Shapely library. I realize now, (after reading the instructions) that using `pt.wkt` will trim the variable therefore, I am changing my code to uses `wkt.dumps(pt, Trim = False)`. I see that `str(pt)` also trims the results.

Question:
Does any other code in Shapely trim the decimals?

`pt.x` or `pt.y` or `pt.xy` sometimes look trimmed but I think this is caused by dumping the coordinates in a Python array. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is not a shapely problem but a more general problem ([Floating Point Math](https://0.30000000000000004.com/))

Comment: I agree for pt.x or pt.y or pt.xy but not for .wkt function.  Manual states "The default settings for the wkt attribute and shapely.wkt.dumps() function are different. By default, the attribute’s value is trimmed of excess decimals, while this is not the case for dumps(), though it can be replicated by setting trim=True."  I am just wondering if this is the case elsewhere in the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docstring of dumps function in the [shapely.wkt script](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/shapely/wkt.py)

```
def dumps(ob, trim=False, **kw):
    """
    Dump a WKT representation of a geometry to a string.
    Parameters
    ----------
    ob :
        A geometry object of any type to be dumped to WKT.
    trim : bool, default False
        Remove excess decimals from the WKT.
    rounding_precision : int
        Round output to the specified number of digits.
        Default behavior returns full precision.
    output_dimension : int, default 3
        Force removal of dimensions above the one specified.
    Returns
    -------
    input geometry as WKT string
    """
    return geos.WKTWriter(geos.lgeos, trim=trim, **kw).write(ob)
```

You can see

- that `trim=False` is the default
- you can set a rounding precision (numpy precision) and an output dimension (for 2D and 3D geometries)

For the other codes that trim the decimals if you do [a search for Trim in the shapely  code](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/search?q=Trim) you find

- [wkt.py](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/0e075e18177f5f42b83e5ca223975c69356c6a77/shapely/wkt.py)
- [geos.py](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/9667fe86b6668deb319e6eb0479bc84e5f6e73ee/shapely/geos.py) in the WKTWriter class (imported by wkt.py)

Knowing that Shapely and GEOS cannot reduce precision (floating-point precision problem, [How to deal with rounding errors in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036167/835653), [Rounding all coordinates in shapely?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/188739/2581)) this problem will always exist.

Example :

```
pt = Point(0.56789, 0.63245)
np.array(pt)
array([0.56789, 0.63245]) #the coordinates are numpy arrays for the computation
pt.x , pt.y
(0.56789, 0.63245)
pt.xy 
(array('d', [0.56789]), array('d', [0.63245]))
pt.wkt
'POINT (0.56789 0.63245)'
wkt.dumps(pt) # trim=False by default
'POINT (0.5678900000000000 0.6324500000000000)'
wkt.dumps(pt, trim=True) # = pt.wkt
'POINT (0.56789 0.63245)'
wkt.dumps(pt, trim=True, rounding_precision=3)
'POINT (0.568 0.632)'
np.round(pt,3)
array([0.568, 0.632])
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize Shapely depended so much on GEOS.  I will have a look at that also.